# Entity Framework 7 - SET IDENTITY_INSERT skips entity id mapping - Fails to insert values

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, dnx50

I have a simple Entity Class as under:

```
[Table("Grade")]
public class Grade
{
    //Tried changing this annotation to Identity
    //[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None), Key]
    [Key]
    public int GradeId { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to seed this with EF7 and CSVHelper for DNX 5 project I am working, as under

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, false)){
CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
IEnumerable<Grade> grades = csvReader.GetRecords<Grade>();

using (_context.Database.BeginTransaction()) 
{
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Grade] ON");
_context.Grades.AddRange(grades);
_context.SaveChanges();
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Grade] OFF");
}}
```

If I comment the using (_context.Database.BeginTransaction()) line error for IDENTITY_INSERT OFF appears though code gets compiled

However with the BeginTransaction() the following error appears

[image]

CSV File used for this project (CSVReader is working fine- returning all columns and data as shown under)

[image]

[image]

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: is this code first? it appears the column GradeName is integer type in the database.

Comment: Nope, The GradeName is nvarchar, I checked.

Comment: After adding following code error is gone, but nothing is seeded.. no error nothing working, debug shows data from CSV is properly fetched. protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Grade>().HasKey(a => a.GradeId);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

Comment: An addendum to this question, provided as an answer below, was deleted yesterday. If you still want an answer to this old question, or you think it could still be useful to the community, please edit your question with the new information. Alternatively please consider deleting the question.